# Powershell: count members of a AD group

Tags: powershell, count

**RECIEVED AN EXAMPLE I COULD USE AND CORRECTED CODE**

My current question is how to count amount of members in a group versus printing out all members of a group (which includes their ID name or PC name). The commented out code prints each member. I just want to count them.

I've tried $members.count, $member.count and $string.count in my foreach loop but nothing prints out. Please help

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$pathEmpty = "C:\Temp\groupsEmpty.txt"

Clear-Content $pathEmpty

$Header = `
"Group ID Name" + "|" + `
"Display Name" + "|" + `
"Description" + "|" + `
"Members"


#Write out the header
$Header | Out-File $pathEmpty -Append


$emptys = get-adgroup -properties name, displayname, description, members -filter  name -like "WA*" -or name -like "workstation*"} `
 | Select name, displayname, description, members

foreach ($empty in $emptys)
{
#clears previous 
$members = ""
foreach ($member in $empty.members)
  {
    $string = $member.substring(3,$member.indexof(",")-3)
    #$members = $members + ":" + $string
    $string.count 
  }
$listing =`
$empty.Name + "|" + `
$empty.DisplayName + "|" + `
$empty.Description + "|" + `
$members

$listing | Out-File $pathEmpty -Append
}
```

I made an edit based on Alex McKenzie's comment. The initial example you gave me made issues. 
I tried adding some edits to it but I get a error: **Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try
 the command again.**

```
foreach ($empty in $emptys)
{
#clears previous 
$members = ""
foreach ($member in $empty.members)
  {
    #$string = $member.substring(3,$member.indexof(",")-3)
    #$members = $members + ":" + $string

    if($member -eq $null){
        $users = 0
        }
    else{
        $users = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $($_.DistinguishedName)).Count
        #$users.count
    }
  }
```

**Below is my finished code. I just made separate .txt files for each things I needed and will just separately import them into excel.** **QUESTION FIXED**

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

##########################################################################
#This Section involves filtering WA groups and retriving their information
#In the info section (aka Notes section) is very important to look
#over if groups require approvals or not

##########################################################################

$pathAll = "C:\Temp\groupsEALL.txt"

Clear-Content $pathALL

$Header = `
"Group ID Name" + "|" + `
"Description" + "|" + `
"Notes Field" + " |" + "Members"


#Write out the header
$Header | Out-File $pathALL -Append

 $emptys = get-adgroup -properties name, description, members, info -filter {name -like "WA*" -or name -like "workstation*"} `
 | Select name, description, members, info

foreach ($empty in $emptys)
{

#clears previous 
$members = ""
foreach ($member in $empty.members)
  {
    #$users = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $member.DistinguishedName).Count
    $string = $member.substring(3,$member.indexof(",")-3)
    $members = $members + ":" + $string
   }

$listing =`
$empty.Name + "|" + `
$empty.Description + "|" + `
$empty.Info + "|" + `
$members

$listing | Out-File $pathALL -Append
}

################################################################
#This next section will determine the member count in the groups

################################################################

$pathCount = "C:\Temp\Groupcount.txt"
Clear-Content $pathcount

$groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {(name -like "WA*") -or (name -like "workstation*")}
foreach($group in $groups){
 #initializing
 $countUser = ""
   $countUser = ((get-Adgroup $group -properties members).members).count


"The group $($group.Name) has $countUser user(s)." | Out-File $pathCount -Append
}
```

I add a counter in original script if I want it to get count as well

```
foreach ($empty in $emptys)
{

#clears previous 
$members = ""
#initialize member counting
$count = 0
foreach ($member in $empty.members)
  {
    #counts how many members
    $count += 1
    $countSum = "The group $($group.Name) has $count user(s)."
    $string = $member.substring(3,$member.indexof(",")-3)
    $members = $members + ":" + $string
   }
    $listing =`
$empty.Name + "|" + `
$empty.Description + "|" + `
#$empty.Info + "|" + `
$empty.info + "|" + `
$members + "|" + $countSum

$listing | Out-File $pathALL -Append
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet would solve this in a much more efficient way than you're tying.

As an example:

```
$users = @(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Group Name')
$users.count
132
```

EDIT:

In order to clarify things, and to make your script simpler. Here's a generic script that will work for your environment that outputs the user count for each group matching your filters.

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {(name -like "WA*") -or (name -like "workstation*")}
foreach($group in $groups){
  $countUser = @(Get-ADGroupMember $group.DistinguishedName).count
  Write-Host "The group $($group.Name) has $countUser user(s)."
}
```

Comment: This works when I do them individually. When I try to incorporate it into my code it doesn't work. See my edit please

Comment: This is when I use the code in the F:\ part of powershell instead of my actual code____________________________________________________________________________
PS F:\> $users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'WA-ABERIN'

____________________________________________________________________________
PS F:\> $users.count
2

______________________

Comment: Try setting `$name = $member.DistinguishedName`. I don't think that nesting the `$_.DistinguishedName` inside a command is working.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand what you are saying.
So: 

    **$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity** then 
    **$users = $member.DistinguishedName** and lastly
    **$users.count**
?

Comment: No. Acutally, it would be best to have `$users = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $($_.DistinguishedName)).Count` be `$users = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $member.DistinguishedName).Count`. Also, print out `$member.DistinguishedName` to make sure it has a value

Comment: This doesn't work still for Identity command. The other code you showed does so I will try and figure out how to make it connect with my code. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

easy way to do it:
To get the actual user count:

```
$ADInfo = Get-ADGroup -Identity '<groupname>' -Properties Members
$AdInfo.Members.Count
```

and you get the count easily, it is pretty fast as well for 20k+ users too

Comment: I think this is much a better way to go. The first technique of using Get-ADGroupMember was failing for me with  a `Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded` error.  My organization is rather large with 10,000+ Ids in a group.  I bet that Get-ADGroup is a much lighter weight method and is not enumerating all the properties on every ID in the group.

Comment: ` (Get-ADGroup $Groupname -property members).members.count' retrieves only one (potentially large) record from the DC.  The members attribute contains a list of the DNs of all members.  

Retrieving every member using `Get-ADGroupMember` is wasteful for flat groups if you only want the count.  It does a lookup for each DN in the members list and returns the AD principal object which includes DN, Name, ObjectGUID, ObjectClass, SID,....

Answer (score 7):

Every response has missed one detail.  What if the group only has 1 user.

```
$count = @(get-adgroupmember $group).count
```

Put the command in the @() wrapper so that the result is an array no matter what, so even if it is 1 item, you get a count.

Answer (score 2):

```
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Client Services' -Recursive ; $users.count
```

The above one-liner gives a clean count of recursive members found. Simple, easy, and one line.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: unless the group only has 1 user.  Why go thru the work of saving data to a variable you don't need?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot utilize the `ActiveDirectory` Module or the `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet, you can do it with  the LDAP "in chain"-matching rule:

```
$GroupDN = "CN=MyGroup,OU=Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=tld"
$LDAPFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$GroupDN))"

# Ideally using an instance of adsisearcher here:
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $LDAPFilter
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx) for additional LDAP matching rules implemented in Active Directory

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, you'll need to import the active directory module, then use the get-adgroupmember, and then measure-object.    For example, to get the number of users belonging to the group "domain users", do the following:

```
Import-Module activedirecotry
Get-ADGroupMember "domain users" | Measure-Object
```

When entering the group name after "Get-ADGroupMember", if the name is a single string with no spaces, then no quotes are necessary.    If the group name has spaces in it, use the quotes around it.

The output will look something like:

```
Count    : 12345
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

Note - importing the active directory module may be redundant if you're already using PowerShell for other AD admin tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Something I'd like to share..

`$adinfo.members` actually give twice the number of actual members.  `$adinfo.member` (*without the "s"*) returns the correct amount.  Even when dumping `$adinfo.members` & `$adinfo.member` to screen outputs the lower amount of members.

No idea how to explain this!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Get-ADGroupMember 'Group name' | measure-object | select count
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$group = Get-ADGroup -Identity your-group-name -Properties *

$group.members | count
```

This worked for me for a group with over 17000 members.

Answer (score 0):

here my PS script for **"Domain Users"**. @Zsolt Varga https://stackoverflow.com/a/42520249/1747983 didn't work for me on Domain users

@AlexMcKenzie `Get-ADGroupMember` has a limit [Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46078880/1747983)

```
PS C:\> $ADInfo = Get-ADGroup -Identity 'Domain Users' -Properties Members
PS C:\> $AdInfo.Members.Count
0
PS C:\> $Group="Domain Users"
PS C:\> $GroupDN = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group).DistinguishedName
PS C:\> $members = DSget group $GroupDN -members
PS C:\> $members.count
177
```

Root cause is the **"Domain Users"** group are likely for most Users the "Primary Group" and not via members attribute, see https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/78wq43/comment/doxgi6d/