# Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to pull groups in from a text file and one of my groups is too large, 80,000 people.

How do I get this to work l, it outputs how I want it.

```
$groups = Get-Content c:\temp\ADGroups.txt

foreach($group in $groups) {
    @(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties Member| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Member).Count
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group |
        Get-ADObject -Properties Name, DisplayName |
        Select-Object -Property @{n="Username";e={$_.Name}}, DisplayName,
            @{n="AD Group";e={$group}} |
        Export-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\GroupsInfo.CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The number of objects that `Get-ADGroupMember` can return is restricted by a limit in the [ADWS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908.aspx) (Active Directory Web Services):

> `MaxGroupOrMemberEntries`
>
> 5000
>
> Specifies the maximum number of group members (recursive or non-recursive), group memberships, and authorization groups that can be retrieved by the Active Directory module `Get-ADGroupMember`, `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`, and `Get-ADAccountAuthorizationGroup` cmdlets. Set this parameter to a higher value if you anticipate these cmdlets to return more than 5000 results in your environment.

According to [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/dbb3777c-dd14-4e3a-8690-103d991e2b85/how-do-i-resolve-the-size-limit-exceeded-for-getadgroupmember-error-when-listing-a-group-with?forum=winserverpowershell) you should be able to work around it by querying group objects and expanding their `member` property (if you can't increase the limit on the service):

```
Get-ADGroup $group -Properties Member |
    Select-Object -Expand Member |
    Get-ADUser -Property Name, DisplayName
```

Beware, though, that this is likely to be slow, because you'll be sending thousands of requests. It might be better to build a hashtable of all users:

```
$users = @{}
Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Property Name, DisplayName | ForEach-Object {
    $users[$_.DistinguishedName] = $_
}
```

so that you can look them up by their distinguished name:

```
Get-ADGroup $group -Properties Member |
    Select-Object -Expand Member |
    ForEach-Object { $users[$_] }
```

Comment: NOTE: there's a gotcha hiding here.  If working with a user's primary group (typically `Domain Users`), the user isn't listed in the group's `members` property & the group doesn't show in the user's `memberof` property.  Instead you have to query the user's `PrimaryGroupId` propery (see https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8ivat1/getaduser_memberof_not_displaying_primary_group/ for more)

Comment: Note: The [DSGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46079965/361842) approach doesn't have this issue.

Comment: @Ansgar - Your solution using $users hashtable is cool, however how to prevent memory getting clogged in case of gigantic directories? (some groups contain >15000 members) and user objects >100K.

Answer (score 14):

I was hitting the 5000 limit with Get-ADGroupMember.

You can use Get-ADUser with the -LDAPFilter parameter to get group members. It's quick and supports >5000 entries.

```
$groups = @(
    "group1"
    "group2"
    "group3"
)

Foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberof=CN=$group,OU=Groups,OU=rest,DC=of,DC=distinguished,DC=name))" | Export-Csv "C:\$group.csv"
}
```

It looks like you can build up complex filters with this method. I needed to quickly return enabled members from some extremely large groups. The filter I used for this was:

`"(&(objectCategory=user)(!useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(memberof=CN=$group,OU=Groups,OU=rest,DC=of,DC=distinguished,DC=name))"`

Comment: If you wanted something less complex / aren't familiar with LDAP Filters, you can use this: `Get-ADUser -Filter "memberof -eq 'CN=$group,OU=Groups,OU=rest,DC=of,DC=distinguished,DC=name'`

Comment: @ferrell_io I'm assuming you meant to include a closing double quotation `"` at the end of that?

Comment: Also the LDAP filter can be used to query groups recursively using LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN... This looks like: "(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=<yourgroupDNhere>))"  Found here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/crowdkb/active-directory-user-filter-does-not-search-nested-groups-715130424.html

Comment: This is assuming all members are from same domain, which is not the case for many companies. And also it lists only first level members. If you have nesting groups, you are not getting whole picture of members.

Comment: Same domain is implied given it needs to run in a user context? Recursion is supported -see the comment above yours. I've just tested this and it works, however it is slower as you might expect. More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax#operators -see 'LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN'

Answer (score 6):

I hear this is a limitation of the AD Webservices that actually service the requests from powershell cmdlets. The maximum size is 5000. But you can try the dsget command, although you will need to get a little creative.

`$GroupDN = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group).DistinguishedName` will give you the DN of the group.

Use the `DSget` like this.

`$members = DSget group $GroupDN -members` This will give you the list of DNs of all members.

Feed that to a `Get-ADUser` cmdlet in a pipe or `foreach` loop and you are good to go.

Comment: I have tested this on a group of 5600 users and worked. Pretty fast too.

Comment: DSget threw a 'not recognized' error when I tried this. I needed to go to Windows 'programs and features' and enable DS Tools. The switch is hidden in the 2016 server  'Add Roles...wizard' on the **Features** tab. Path is `Remote Server Admin Tools/Role Admin Tools/AD DS and AD LDS Tools/AD DS tools`. I didn't change any roles, just clicked through until I reached the **Select Features** page of the wizard.

Comment: Quick note on this... I tried it and ran into the following:
1) The results returned from dsget are in quotations. Need to strip.
2) The results returned from dsget cannot handle "foreign" characters so piping to get-aduser is a no-go on those entries.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the -resultpagesize parameter. The highest value you can specify is 2147483647.
So:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -resultpagesize 2147483647 |
    Select-Object -Property @{n="Username";e={$_.Name}}, DisplayName,
        @{n="AD Group";e={$group}} |
    Export-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\GroupsInfo.CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: The mentioned Parameter is not available for PS Version 5.0

Comment: If anything, it should be `-ResultSetSize`, but while these parameters are defined for `Get-ADUser` and `Get-ADComputer`, for instance, they are _not_ for [`Get-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember) - at least per the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did mine.  I needed to extract more than 25k machines from a security group.

```
$Groups = gc C:\Temp\Groups.txt
$results = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
Get-ADGroup $Group -Properties Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Member | Get-ADObject -Properties Name
}
$results | Export-csv "C:\Temp\Groups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all of the members of a group quickly (mine had 85k members)

```
$groupMembers = Get-ADGroup -Identity $group -Server $domainGroupIsIn -Properties Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Member ;
```

or if you need to filter some
$whereMatch = $recipient.DistinguishedName.Remove(0, $index); # limits to a domain or container

```
$groupMembers = Get-ADGroup -Identity $group -Server $domainGroupIsIn -Properties Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Member | Where {$_ -match $whereMatch};
```

Answer (score -1):

Just increase the limit from ADUC --> View --> Filter Option - Maximum number of options displayed per folder.

That's it. Try again running your command. It takes me 4 days to figure out this and finally it's working.