# Powershell Group Membership -Filtered by OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to look in `OU A` and get only the members of each group that are in `OU B`.

My script gets the information I want, but it's all in one list, not broken up per group, which makes it useless.

Ideally, I'd like to export to excel with column A having group names (not DNs) and column B having groups members.

I appreciate any help. See below for what I've already got:

```
$DNs = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU A" | ForEach { $_.DistinguishedName }
ForEach ($i in $DNs) {
    Get-ADComputer -Filter {memberof -eq $i} -SearchBase "OU B" | Select-Object Name
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `DistinguishedName` returned by `Get-ADGroupMember` has the OU information you can remove the `CN=ObjectName,` from the front and then compare the text. Then using `-eq` makes sure that subOUs don't match.

```
$Data = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU A" | ForEach-Object {
    $GroupName = $_.Name
    Get-ADGroupMember $_.DistinguishedName |
        Where-Object {($_.DistinguishedName -replace '^CN=.*?,OU','OU') -eq "OU=B,DC=Example"} |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name = $GroupName
                Member = $_.Name
            }
        }
}

$Data | Export-CSV C:\Example.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Alternatively you could retrieve the OU B objects before hand and then check if the member is in that collection. This approach is more clean since it doesn't rely on text parsing, but is slightly more resource intensive.

```
$OUBObjects = Get-ADObject -Filter * -SearchBase "OU B" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$Data = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU A" | ForEach-Object {
    $GroupName = $_.Name
    Get-ADGroupMember $_ |
        Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -in $OUBObjects} |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name = $GroupName
                Member = $_.Name
            }
        }
}

$Data | Export-CSV C:\Example.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Edit:

Here is the code using `Get-ADGroup -Properties Members` instead of `Get-ADGroupMember`. Note that this will return DNs instead of sAMAccountNames

```
$OUBObjects = Get-ADObject -Filter * -SearchBase "OU B" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$Data = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU A" -Properties Members | ForEach-Object {
    $GroupName = $_.Name
    $_.members |
        Where-Object {$_ -in $OUBObjects} |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name = $GroupName
                Member = $_
            }
        }
}

$Data | Export-CSV C:\Example.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This seems to work; however, I receive an error multiple times: "Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded" Any way around that?

Comment: @Brandon Answer updated using Ansgars solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078880/get-adgroupmember-the-size-limit-for-this-request-was-exceeded) by using `Get-ADGroup -Properties Members` rather than `Get-ADGroupMember`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this work in my environment, so it should work in yours with some necessary changes.  Let me know if you have any questions and I'll be able to assist.

To get the AD Users in a given group A and B:
    $ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase "OU=A,DC=zone,DC=domain,DC=com"
    $report = @()
    Foreach ($Group in ($ADGroups | ? { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*OU=B*" }))
    {
        try{
            $members = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $group.Name
            $object = [pscustomobject]@{
                GroupName = $group.Name; 
                GroupMembers = "$($members.name -join ";")";
            }
            $report += $object
        }
        catch 
        {
            Write-Host "Unable to find AD Group Members"
        }
    }

```
$report | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Temp\Test.csv"
```

To get the ADComputers in B from ADGroups in A and B:

```
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase "OU=A,DC=zone,DC=domain,DC=com"
$report = @()
Foreach ($Group in ($ADGroups | ? { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*OU=B*" }))
{
    try{
        <#
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $group.Name
        #>
        $members = -Filter * -Property MemberOf -SearchBase "OU=B,DC=zone,DC=domain,DC=com" | Where-Object { $_.memberOf -like "*$($group.name)*" }
        $object = [pscustomobject]@{
            GroupName = $group.Name; 
            GroupMembers = "$($members.name -join ";")";
        }
        $report += $object
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Host "Unable to find AD Group Members"
    }
}

$report | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Temp\Test.csv"
```

The second condition works, but I had no results in my own network for the limited search I was performing.  Try it out and we can work on adjusting it as needed.

Comment: This gets the Groups that are in both OU A and OU B rather than the Groups that are in OU A and the Computer Object Members that are in OU B.

Comment: @websch01ar I tried this and it only creates a blank CSV. I assume I only needed to change the OU paths and the Output path? As BenH pointed out, I want the computers in "OU B" that are members of the groups in "OU A". Sorry, if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Correct, I made it where you need to set the value for "A" and "B" and point the path for the CSV file where you want it.  This will give you users in the ADGroups that match your requirements.  I admit I could not mesh your narrative with your sample code.

Comment: Brandon, I adjusted the script some, and I hope it meets your needs.