# List Members of multible AD Groups with more than 5000 Users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How could I get a List of Members on multible AD Groups with more than 5000 Users 
Example:
Group1 = includes 6000 Members and Group2
Group2 = includes 7000 Members

the result of the get-adgroupmember of Group1 should 13000

how can I do that? Here I have the Problem, that it will not look in sub groups recursive will not work with get-adgroup

```
$group = "group1"
$ADInfo = Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group -Properties Members 
$outputfile = $group
$ADInfo.Members | get-aduser | Select name, enabled, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName  

#$ADInfo.Members | get-aduser | Select name, enabled, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName  | Export-Csv c:\temp\$outputfile-member.csv -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation

# to show output
$members = @()
$members = $ADInfo.members
$members.count
```

Comment: You can try, then post your code here and we'll tell you where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With groups that large, it will be slow, but this should do what you want:

```
$groups = 'group1', 'group2'  # array of group names

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Write-Host "Working on group '$group'"
    $result = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | ForEach-Object {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $_.distinguishedName | Select-Object Name, Enabled, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName
    }
    # show result on screen
    $result | Format-Table -AutoSize

    # write to export file
    $result | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\$group-members.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, tanks for your help, but in this case you would need to know the name of all groups, What about you just know the group1 name and get a result of it in one script

Comment: @vespavbb Yes, because your code also seems to know all groups. If you want to find all groups, you can do `$groups = Get-ADGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName`. You might want to look at the parameters for [Get-ADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup?view=win10-ps) first to see if you can restrict the number of groups returned.

Comment: Isn't `Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive` gonna run into the default 5000 `MaxGroupOrMemberEntries` ADWS limit?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Hm. looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078880/get-adgroupmember-the-size-limit-for-this-request-was-exceeded) you might be right..

Comment: yes, get-ADGroupMember - Recursive will not work #### The size limit for this request was exceeded

Comment: @vespavbb I didn't think of the 5000 max limit when i posted. Please have a look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078880/get-adgroupmember-the-size-limit-for-this-request-was-exceeded).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to adjust the `MaxGroupOrMemberEntries` parameter in ADWS on the DC you are targeting. You can see information on ADWS defaults [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd391908(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

You could do something like the following, which is potentially convoluted:

```
function Get-ADGroupMembers
{
        param ($groupname)

    Get-ADGroupMember $groupname | where ObjectClass -eq 'Group' | ForEach-Object {
            $_.Name
            Get-ADGroupMembers $_.Name
        }

}

$maingroup = 'group1'
$subgroups = Get-ADGroupMembers $maingroup
$allGroups = @($maingroup)+@($subgroups)
$regexEscapes = $allGroups |% { [regex]::Escape($_) }
$filter = "CN=({0})" -f ($regexEscapes -join "|")
$output = foreach ($group in $allGroups) {
    Get-AdGroup $group -Properties Members | Select @{n='Members';e={$_.Members -notmatch $filter}}
}
$output.Members
```

**Explanation:**

The function will list the `Name` property value for each recursively discovered member group.

Since the `-notmatch` regex operator is used in filtering, a regex match string needs to be constructed. There could be multiple groups so the `|` (regex OR) character needs to be used.

The `[regex]::Escape` method escapes all backslashes and other special regex characters that may appear in the name strings.

`$output` is an array of `PSCustomObject`s that contain the `Members` property. The `Members` property contains the DN of all members that are users.

---

Non-PowerShell commands may be better suited for this particular case if the ADWS default limits are not modified.

Comment: ok thanks, not bad. But how can I modify the output to get Name, SamAccountname, enabled instead of the cn path

Comment: Then you need to pipe the results of `Get-ADGroup` command into `Get-ADUser`