# Recursive DFS in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, recursion, depth-first-search

I am trying to do a graph search on a global distribution group with multiple users and nested groups in order to determine who is a member and who isn't. However, my code is flawed because it seems to return true no matter what the input. It seems to never even run the Search function...:

```
function DFS($dName, $group) {
    $visited = [pscustomobject]@{}

    function Search($dName, $group) {
        foreach ($_dName in $group.members) {
            if (!$visited."$_dName") {
                Add-Member -InputObject $visited -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_dName -Value $true

                if ($_dName -match "Distribution Groups") {
                    $sub_group = Get-ADGroup -Identity $_dName -Properties members
                    return Search -dName $dName -group $sub_group
                } elseif ($_dName -match $dName) {
                    return $true
                }
            }
        }

        return $false
    }

    Write-Output $visited
    return Search -dName $dName -group $group
}

$global_distro = Get-ADGroup -Identity globaldistro -Properties members

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'DC=Domain,DC=local'

foreach ($user in $users) {
    # Skip OU's we don't care about
    if ($user.DistinguishedName -inotmatch "OU=OU1|OU=OU2|OU=OU3") {
        continue
    }

    $result = DFS -dName $user.DistinguishedName -group $global_distro

    if ($result) { Write-Output "Found $($user.Name)" }
    else { Write-Output "Did not find $($user.Name)" }
}
```

Comment: Did you build this in stages? Meaning one segment at a time, to make sure you are getting back from that code block what you'd expect, before adding another code block? From a best practice perspective, reconsider your naming convention to be what is defined in the PowerShell docs. DFS??? is normally an abbreviation used for Windows Distributed File System, not something dealing with AD groups. You don't really need those return,/continue keywords for what your use case needs. Sure you could, but just saying.

Comment: @postanote DFS stands for depth first search here. Thanks for the tips, I did not know DFS stood for something important in Windows... should probably name it something different.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `Get-AdGroupMember -Recursive`? Are you hitting the 5000 object limit or something?

Comment: @BaconBits I was not aware that flag existed, that's exactly what I needed! Working now, thank you. Still not sure what exactly is wrong with my code in OP, should not be hitting that limit.

Comment: No, no, the 5,000 object limit is one that `Get-AdGroupMember` will hit. It's a limitation of AD web services that several commands might hit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46079714/696808