# The size limit for this request was exceeded

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I get the following message when I use code,

The size limit for this request was exceeded

$Group1 = Read-Host "Enter the First AD Group"

Get-adgroupmember -identity $Group1 | Get-ADObject  -Properties SamAccountName, DisplayName, EmployeeID | Select-Object Name, displayName, EmployeeID|export-csv C:\Users\user1\Desktop\ADGroupAudit\adgroup.csv

Is there a way to get all of the Users from that AD group?

Comment: try with the `member` property directly: `(Get-ADGroup $Group1 -Properties member).member | Get-ADObject ....`

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Max size is 5000.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078880/get-adgroupmember-the-size-limit-for-this-request-was-exceeded