# Invoke-Command errors with large computer list

Tags: powershell

I have a script block that I am attempting to run against a large list of computers.

Essentially:

```
$servers = Get-Adcomputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Servers,DC=Domain,DC=com'
Invoke-Command -asjob -throttlelimit 100 -computername $servers.Name -scriptblock $myscriptblock
```

When running this command against an OU with a smaller count (~ under 5,000), it works without issue.

When targeting an OU with 9,000 computer objects, it immediately gives me the standard error:

`Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings.`

**Some side notes:**

- I have already tried using `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` (and then removing `.Name` from the `-ComputerName` param) and it does not help.
- The work-around, which I have not attempted yet mainly due to the downstream changes it will require, is to split my `$servers` list, but I do not feel like that should be required as it defeats the purpose of this function to some degree (especially when doing `-asjob`)
- Changing `-ComputerName` to `-ComputerName $Servers.Name[1..10]` also has the command run without fail.

This feels related to ADWS and [Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078880/get-adgroupmember-the-size-limit-for-this-request-was-exceeded), however I am having issues finding more information on other potential work arounds.

Comment: Maybe one or more computer names are not valid.

Comment: many likely are, but those errors don't surface until you run a `Receive-Job`.  This is also confirmed as I can use the `[]` to limit to say the first `[1..4000]` and it runs and completes without the invoke-command error

Comment: does it still run if you do `[4001..9000]` or whatever the upper limit is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All elements of an array of computer names passed to the `-ComputerName` parameter of [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) are validated *up front*, and only names of the following forms are accepted:

- a DNS host name (e.g. `server1` or `server1.contoso.com`)
- an IPv4 address (e.g. `192.168.0.1`)
- an IPv6 address (e.g., `fe80::3efb:9d29:3cc5:33d5`

`Invoke-Command` refuses to run if at least one invalid name is present,<sup>[1]</sup> and your symptom indeed implies that there are invalid names among the values returned by `$servers.Name`.

While the error message doesn't reveal the specific invalid names, you can find them yourself, by performing the [same validation that `Invoke-Command` does](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/223c6531e1648e269faa8cf866409101aa2b7c0e/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/remoting/commands/PSRemotingCmdlet.cs#L1079-L1093):

```bash
# Outputs all invalid names, if any.
$servers.Name.Where({ [Uri]::CheckHostName($_) -notin 'Dns', 'IPv4', 'IPv6' })
```

---

Note that there is *no* problem with passing `9,000` computer names, as long as all the names are valid.

You can verify this with the following test command (targets the same computer, run *with elevation*), which runs successfully:

```bash
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (, $env:COMPUTERNAME * 9000) -ThrottleLimit 2 { 'hi' }
```

---

<sup>[1] If you use `-AsJob` with `Invoke-Command`, you'll have to use `Receive-Job` on the resulting job object to see the failure.</sup>

Comment: `$servers.Name.Where({ [Uri]::CheckHostName($_) -notin 'Dns', 'IPv4', 'IPv6' })` helped.  Looks like a single machine with spaces at the end of the name.  Sorry for being a dick in original comment.  All my testing with smaller sizes must have avoided the single machine somehow.