# Copy AD group members from Group A to Group B

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I'm try to write an script which copy's member from "Group A" to "group B" but its failing as Group A has over 10000 members

I have use following script

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group A" | ForEach-Object {
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group B" -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty Name

    If ($members -contains $_.Name) {
      Write-Host "$user exists in the group"
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group B" -Members $_.distinguishedName
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded
At line:1 char:1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code, can be simplified to this:

```bash
$dnGroupA = (Get-ADGroup 'Group A').DistinguishedName
$dnGroupB = (Get-ADGroup 'Group B').DistinguishedName

# Get the members of Group A NOT being a member of Group B:
$members = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(memberOf=$dnGroupA)(!memberOf=$dnGroupB))"
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $dnGroupB -Members $members
```

This should also overcome the member limitation of `Get-ADGroupMember` mentioned in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078880/get-adgroupmember-the-size-limit-for-this-request-was-exceeded).